# How do I keep my loftwing from stalling?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

While flying around with my loftwing, I frequently get into the situation where my loftwing starts stalling. I start moving slower and slower until it stops gliding and just flaps its wings as it begins to fall. This especially happens if I'm trying to go up; if I try to go down, the loftwing usually starts gliding again.

The only way out of this that I've seen is to press the <kbd>A</kbd> button to make it charge, but that is over quickly and I get right back to stalling. The help screen that appears when you press the <kbd>2</kbd> button doesn't say anything about what to do in this situation. Sometimes if I wildly wave around the Wii Remote, my loftwing gets going again, but I can't figure out what to do with that.

So how can I prevent my loftwing from stalling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-watching the flying tutorial shows this isn't very well explained at all, but you almost had it: A vertical swing of the Wii Remote is necessary for wing flapping, and is where you are supposed to be getting most of your bird power from.

Comment: Fly up and glide back down to maintain speed

Comment: To be clear, it's a vertical up and down swing, right? I'm guessing it's supposed to represent flapping the wings.

Comment: Yeah you're supposed to swing up and then down, less than a sword swing, but more than just aiming your direction.

Comment: Imagine the motion you make when you flip a pancake in a pan, that should do the trick.